# cfexecute command line

Tags: coldfusion, wkhtmltopdf, coldfusion-8, coldfusionbuilder, cfexecute

I've just installed [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) which converts webpages to pdfs.

I can run it from the command line on the server like so:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.co.uk c:\google.pdf
```

wkhtmltopdf was added added to the path environmental variable. The real path to the exe is C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe

I now want to run this with ColdFusion 8 using cfexecute.

```
<cfexecute name="c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe"
        arguments="wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com c:\google.pdf"
        timeout="10" />
```

I've tried a few different variations but can't seem to get it to work.

I've also had some "error 5 access is denied" messages but I understand this still might be a syntax issue rather than a rights issue.

Can anyone see issues with my code?

Comment: Your cfexecute is wrong - check [the docs](http://cfdocs.org/cfexecute) and you'll see the `variable` attribute is the CFML variable any response is stored in; you want `arguments` for the parameters passed to the executable.

Comment: oops yeah I forgot to swap that over. I've made the edit above. Still no good.

Answer (score 5):

OK GOT IT WORKING!...

```
<cfexecute name="c:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe" 
        arguments="http://www.google.com C:\google.pdf"
        timeout="10" />
```

Syntax is a bit different from the command line I ran in windows.

Comment: It's not the different syntax, your original version simply made two calls of the same program.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that ColdFusion has the ability to convert HTML to PDF built-in?  See the [cfdocument tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_05.html).

Here is a very simple example that should work:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://www.google.com" timeout="10" />
<cfif cfhttp.StatusCode EQ "200 OK">
    <cfdocument format="PDF" localurl="false">
        <cfoutput>#cfhttp.FileContent#</cfoutput>
    </cfdocument>
<cfelse>
    <p>http request failed [<cfoutput>#cfhttp.StatusCode#</cfoutput>]</p>
</cfif>
```

I don't know the extent of the functionality that you need from the PDF converter but for simple conversions the `cfdocument` tag works pretty well.

Comment: It does but wkhtmltopdf does a more accurate job in conversion in my tests.